# TextInput is not responding when I use TouchableWithoutFeedback in React Native

Tags: react-native

When I remove TouchableWithoutFeedback then Input text is responding otherwise not.
I tried lots but I am not getting any solution there.

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>The a New Game !</Text>
        <Card style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Text>Select a Number</Text>
          <Input
            style={styles.input}
            blurOnSubmit
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={2}
            onChange={numberInputHandler}
            value={enteredValue}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <View>
              <Button style={styles.button} title="Reset" onPress={() => {}} color={Color.accent} />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Button
                style={styles.button}
                title="Confirm"
                onPress={() => {}}
                color={Color.primary}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using zIndex( style={{zIndex: 20}} ) on both TextInput and TouchableWithoutFeedback, and make sure you give a greater value to the TextInput.